# Displaying a specific category in a WP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wp-list-categories

On my WordPress website, I created a page in which I display 9 posts of the category "interviews". Then there is a button ("Charger plus d'interviews") to click if you want to see more posts of the category.

There is a problem in the loop, because when I click on it, it displays posts from all the other categories. 
What shall I do to display only the "interviews" ?

```
<section class="blocs" id="home_article_derniers">
    <div class="iso-container">
    <?php 

    $post_home_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => 'interview',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => 2
    ));

    if($post_home_query->have_posts()){
        while ( $post_home_query->have_posts() ) {
            $post_home_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('loop-post', 'actus');
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
      } ?>
    </div>
</section>

    <div class="separator">
     <a class="btn btn-default more-article" data-paged="1" data-post-not-in="<?php echo implode(',', $array_post_not_in) ?>">Charger plus d'interviews &raquo;</a>

    ?>
    </div>
```

This is the code of the loop :

```
<?php $color = wami_get_first_category_color(get_the_ID()); ?>

  <article data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post post-actu iso-item bloc-infinity <?php echo (isset($phone) ? $phone : '' ) ?> ">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="post-header">

        <?php 
            if(has_post_thumbnail()):
                the_post_thumbnail('actu-hp-small');
            endif;
        ?>

        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="img"></div>
             <div class="background" style="background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>">
             </div>
           </div>
         <div class="post-header-title">
            <?php wami_the_first_category(get_the_ID(), false, $color, true); ?>
         </div>
       </div>

      <div class="post-body">
        <?php
            the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
            /*the_excerpt();*/
        ?>
      </div>
  </a>
 </article>
```

Here's the function

```
function wami_load_more_posts(){
if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
    $paged = $_REQUEST['paged'];
    $post_not_in = explode(',', $_REQUEST['post_not_in']);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post__not_in' => $post_not_in,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    if(isset($_REQUEST['category_in'])){
        $args['category__in'] = $_REQUEST['category_in'];
    }

    $homeblog_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $homeblog_query->have_posts() ):
        while($homeblog_query->have_posts()):
            $homeblog_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('loop-post', 'actus');
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    }
die();
 }
add_action('wp_ajax_wami_load_more_posts', 'wami_load_more_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wami_load_more_posts', 'wami_load_more_posts');
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the AJAX function you use to query for additional posts.

Comment: The code you've shown has got nothing to do with displaying the additional posts. Share the relevant code where the Ajax request is handled.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I posted the code of the loop and the function have-query(). Let me know if you need anything else.

PS just to let you know, I'm a just a designer who tries to work on a code someone else made and that I don't fully understand. I'll try to do my best. :)

Comment: What is “wami” – a plugin, a theme, …? / Most likely your problem lies in that the parameter `category_in` does not get send with the AJAX request.